# Burninate [spreadsheet-gem]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

I would like to request that the tag [spreadsheet-gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet-gem) be burninated because, although it is good for grouping questions, this could be generalized to any ruby gem (library) and it would make sense to have a tag for each one.

Comment: How else would you tag questions about the 'spreadsheet' gem?

Comment: [ruby] [spreadsheet] [other relevant tags]

Comment: But this is about the specific gem. It's not about spreadsheets. I see no reason for this tag to be burned.

Comment: If we had a tag for each gem, that would be hundreds of tags, each used once or twice

Comment: And we have that. :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191 details the reasons for tag burnination, if you really think it should be burninated, you should probably add in some justification.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It only has [8 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet-gem) from the last 6 years, with no tag wiki, so I would be in favour of burning it.